# convert uploaded image to grey scale in PHP

Tags: image-processing

I have a script that uploads a picture and resizes it, which all works fine, but I wanted to be able to strip the color out of the image leaving it black and white (various shades of grey essentially). I wasn't sure of how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
<?php 
$source_file = "test_image.jpg";

$im = ImageCreateFromJpeg($source_file); 

$imgw = imagesx($im);
$imgh = imagesy($im);

for ($i=0; $i<$imgw; $i++)
{
        for ($j=0; $j<$imgh; $j++)
        {

                // get the rgb value for current pixel

                $rgb = ImageColorAt($im, $i, $j); 

                // extract each value for r, g, b

                $rr = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                $gg = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                $bb = $rgb & 0xFF;

                // get the Value from the RGB value

                $g = round(($rr + $gg + $bb) / 3);

                // grayscale values have r=g=b=g

                $val = imagecolorallocate($im, $g, $g, $g);

                // set the gray value

                imagesetpixel ($im, $i, $j, $val);
        }
}

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
?>
```

Notice that I have shamelessly ripped this snippet from [this article](http://bubble.ro/How_to_convert_an_image_to_grayscale_using_PHP.html), which I found using a google search with the terms: *php convert image to grayscale*

[ edit ]
And from the comments, if you use PHP5, you could also use:

```
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
```

Comment: That's using a naiive color->greyscale conversion. Human eyes are far more green-sensitive, so a better conversion formula will give the green component a higher weight than the red/blue.

Comment: Of course. I have added `imagefilter`, which only works for PHP5, I **presume** (and hope) this one uses a more sophisticated method.

Comment: @yuri:-sir i am using above script of yours and i am getting error i image cannot be display because it contain error.i think this create problem(header('Content-type: image/png');)

Comment: @AnkurSaxena are you sure the source image exists? Try adding a few debug statements, and maybe use view-source: on the image, to see if you could get a more descriptive error.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
But every single method mentioned here is not working for 100%. All of them is counting on color palette of the image, but the shades of gray might be missing and another color from the palette is used.

My solution is to replace colors in the color palette using imagecolorset.

```
$colorsCount = imagecolorstotal($img->getImageResource());
for($i=0;$i<$colorsCount;$i++){
    $colors = imagecolorsforindex( $img->getImageResource() , $i );
    $g = round(($colors['red'] + $colors['green'] + $colors['blue']) / 3);
    imagecolorset($img->getImageResource(), $i, $g, $g, $g);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### It's better to use command tool to convert such type of image.

While animated gif is also support.

E.g:

```
$file = 'image.jpg';
$file = 'image.gif';
$file = 'image.png';
$image_type = getimagesize($file);

switch (strtolower($image_type['mime'])) {
    case 'image/png':
       exec("convert $file -colorspace Gray dummy.png");
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
       exec("convert $file -colorspace Gray dummy.jpeg");
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
       exec("convert $file -colorspace Gray dummy.gif");
        break;
    default:
        die;
}
```