# Cordova - Insert to web page's database

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, cordova, apache-cordova

I'm developing an app using Apache Cordova for Visual Studio. The purpose of this app is to take a picture using the phone and upload this picture alongside with some other user input data to our company's webpage, that uses a SQL-server Database to store it's data.

So, the question is: How can I insert data to this database so I can show it on the webpage, considering that the app will be used outside of our network? So it can't be a local connection to our database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pictureSource;
 var destinationType;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

On device ready

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}
```

Clean Up

```
function clearCache() {
    navigator.camera.cleanup();
}

var retries = 0;
```

Upload photo taken from camera

```
function onCapturePhoto(fileURI) {
document.getElementById('MyElement').innerHTML = 'Uploading....';
    var win = function (r) {
    clearCache();
    retries = 0;
    document.getElementById('MyElement').innerHTML = '';
    alert('Image Uploaded! Successfully');
};

var fail = function (error) {
    if (retries === 0) {
        retries++;
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById('MyElement').innerHTML = '';
            onCapturePhoto(fileURI);
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        retries = 0;
        clearCache();
        document.getElementById('MyElement').innerHTML = '';
        alert('Something went wrong..Try Again');
    }
};
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
options.params = {};
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://yourserver.com/phpfile.php"), win, fail, options);
}

   function onFail(message) {
    alert(message);
    }
```

Function To Call The Camera

<a href="#" onclick="capturePhoto();">Take Picture</a>

```
   function capturePhoto() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhoto, onFail, {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
    });
    }
```

Php part

```
             <?php
             $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
             $targetPath = "images/".$_FILES['file']['name']; // save uploaded image to images folder
             move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;
             ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But where is the upload to the website's database?

Comment: The $targetPath variable returns the path where the image is, so you save that to your database with mysql

Comment: Fantastic! It uploads to the server, only thing missing is uploading to the database, but that I can do. Thank you sir!

Comment: By the way, any hints on how to convert this image to grayscale? 
Before or after the upload to the server.

Comment: [ok see this php example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245021/convert-uploaded-image-to-grey-scale-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up a secure API that has access to that database. Then, you can make an http POST from your Cordova app to an endpoint that saves the image in the database. You could use base64 encoding to facilitate the transfer of the image data. Then, you could read the images from the database just like usual!

All that you need to do on the Cordova side of things would be send an http request with your image data to the API server. You could do that with vanilla JS ala XMLHttpRequest, or with a Cordova plugin like this https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP.

The server side will be a bit more complicated, as you will need to create an API endpoint that saves the image data into your MS-SQL server. You should check out this high-level explanation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258693(v=sql.80).aspx. There are also Node.js interfaces for MS-SQL servers if that is your fancy.

Comment: Any hints or tutorials on how to do so? Keeping in mind that im New to developing with cordova

Comment: @RafaelMaria, I tried to give you a little insight into where to go from here (see edit). You'll just need your API to do an INSERT statement on you DB with the image passed as a parameter to the HTTP post request.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll read it and try to figure out a solution